# Facebook share dialog disappears immediately

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, dialog

Here is my situation:

I'm using the Facebook SDK 2.4 for Android. I'm publishing a custom open graph story using the standard Facebook share dialog.

ISSUE: the dialog appears and closes right away.

1. I use the standard Facebook Share Dialog (NOT a custom dialog).
2. I use the dialog to share a custom open graph story.
3. The story and action are approved by FB.
4. The app is set to "public".

The share dialog works for developer accounts but still fails for others. I see no discernible reason why that is the case - can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Are your app in public mode? If it's not, only admin/tests can post feed with it.

Comment: It was in public mode but there was a bug in the API which caused it to not accept dialog opens from non-testers. Resolved by the FB team.

Answer (score 1):

Your application must be in **public mode or live** to other users.
**NOTE**: How to set app mode as public or live? The answer is as follow:
Goto **App Review** settings (of developers.facebook.com) and set [Make *app_name* public?] turned On, For this it will ask for you to enter **Privacy Policy URL** in your App's base settings.
**NOTE**: How to get Privacy Policy URL? The answer is as follow:
 [go with this link](https://termsfeed.com/blog/privacy-policy-url-facebook-app/) after getting help to get URL from this link **paste** this in *Privacy Policy URL* box and then go back to *App Review* and turned it On.
Now check your Share Dialogue again 
 
I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your app has to be in the public mode for the same, please refer to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42337953/7012089

Comment: The author said their app is set to 'public'